# Aiogram(FSM) не могу записать данные в дату state

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Проблема с @dp.callback_query_handler

```
class number(StatesGroup):
    number_of_korpus = State()
    number_audit = State()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='nav', state=None)
async def nav_call(callback:types.CallbackQuery):
    await number.number_of_korpus.set()
    await callback.message.answer('Выберите корпус',reply_markup=kb_korpusa)


@dp.callback_query_handler(content_types='text', state=number.number_of_korpus)
async def audit_(callback:types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number_of_korpus']==callback.message.text
    await number.next()
    await callback.message.answer('С помощью клавиатуры введите номер аудитории')


@dp.message_handler(state=number.number_audit)
async def naviga(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text==Text(startswith='1'):
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open"Путь к файлу")
```

Появляется вот такая проблема, как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, не FSC, а FSM.
Во-вторых посмотрите сюда внимательнее.

```
data['number_of_korpus']==callback.message.text
```

Ну что увидели? Ладно, даю подсказку.

```
data['number_of_korpus'] = callback.message.text
```

UPD1.
А еще в `callback_query_handler` не нужен фильтр на `content_types`. Уберите его. Ну и `state=None` также бессмысленный фильтр, так как стоит по умолчанию.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ошибка не вылетает, но он не выдает мне фотографию, которую должен. Можете подсказать, как это устроить? 
Хочу сделать так:
1) Пользователь выбрал корпус с помощью инлайн кнопки
2)Бот попросил его номер аудитории, и пользователь ввел, к примеру : "122", и бот выдает ему этаж плана фотографией, если из примера брать, то первого, т.к первая цифра "1"

Comment: Я думаю это уже не часть этого вопроса, закройте этот нажав на галочку слева от ответа, и создайте новый с конкретными условиями и данными, а также кодом который у вас хоть в каком-то виде должен быть